# Making elements appear as if they share a background

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a to-do web app and I'm trying to achieve a visual effect wherein multiple todos appear to "share" a single background. So, imagine that a user adds a few todos. Their backgrounds appear as a part of a single gradient, with colors transitioning from top todo to bottom todo. This pen should hopefully demonstrate what I want to happen (click the first div):

[Elements 'sharing' a background](https://codepen.io/ArtemPetrov/pen/MWYvyXV)

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <p>CLICK ME</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.inner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, green, blue);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Now this already kind of works, I guess, but only if I manually animate position of the divs. Is there some way to utilize CSS transforms instead? The big problem there is that as soon as a transform is applied to outer div, the fixed child div stops being fixed, completely destroying the 'same background' illusion. you can see it in this pen:

[Illusion fail](https://codepen.io/ArtemPetrov/pen/WNbEoJO)

I read that it's part of the spec and that's just how it is, but thought maybe you CSS wizards here know other ways to achieve this effect, perhaps even without fixed child divs. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Using [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) in css might achieve your goal.

Comment: I think you need a better visual guide to help others help you find a solution. My first thought was "why not have the root parent have the gradient, and the children just have a transparent background? Perhaps you need a black background to show through in your design idea?

Comment: Also, it's important to note that clip is depreciated: `clip-path` is the "new" clip, and it's values can be animated/transitioned. https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/

Comment: @mix3d Oh... Yeah I'll have to see about replacing it with clip-path then, thanks. But yes, I'd like regular background to remain black, and the gradient background to show only through todos. Just like in the pen, except todos will be stacked vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `clip-path`, but one issue is that it doesn't clip the same way as `clip` does, because it only clips the element itself, not child elements under it. Children elements will also get clipped, so they have to be moved to match the new clip position.

https://codepen.io/mix3d/pen/OJPjbGp

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/ is a useful link

Comment: @ArtemPetrov If this worked for you, can you mark this answer as correct?